# RestTemplate.getObjectFor(String url, Class<T> responseType) and RestTemplate.getObjectFor(URI url, Class<T> responseType)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, uri

I have problem with Spring RestTemplate, i try to get data from an address which return JSON. When i use RestTemplate.getObjectFor(String url, Class responseType) i got Exception about Could not read document: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)). But if i use RestTemplate.getObjectFor(URI url, Class responseType) then it works!

Can anyone tell me why that happen?

Here is the configuration for rest template,

```
 @Bean(name = "cernerRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate cernerRestTemplate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    RestTemplate cernerRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    cernerRestTemplate.setRequestFactory(getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    cernerRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
    cernerRestTemplate.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
    return cernerRestTemplate
}

private List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> getInterceptors() {
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
  requestHeaders.put(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*");

  Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
  responseHeaders.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,      MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);

  HeaderHttpRequestInterceptor headerHttpRequestInterceptor = new HeaderHttpRequestInterceptor();
  headerHttpRequestInterceptor.setRequestHeaders(requestHeaders);
  headerHttpRequestInterceptor.setResponseHeaders(responseHeaders);

  BasicAuthenticationRequestInterceptor basicAuthenticationRequestInterceptor =
    new BasicAuthenticationRequestInterceptor(username, password);

  List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
  interceptors.add(basicAuthenticationRequestInterceptor);
  interceptors.add(headerHttpRequestInterceptor);

  return interceptors;
}

private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
  List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
  supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter =
    new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
   mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);

  List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
  messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
  messageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

  return messageConverters;
}

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()
  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
  requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
  requestConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout);
  RequestConfig requestConfig = requestConfigBuilder.build();

  HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
  httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
  httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnPerRoute);
  httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnTotal(maxConnTotal);
  httpClientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(new     CustomSslConnectionSocketFactory());

  return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClientBuilder.build());
}
```